# Is it true that if a polynomial $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ then it is also irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, rational-numbers

I'd expect that it'd be trivially true because $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}$, so any factorisation in $\mathbb{Z}$ would also be a valid factorisation in $\mathbb{Q}$. However, I realise that I could be missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: Google Gauss lemma...and have fun finding the correct version.

Comment: @B.Mehta Yes, that's it $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$

Comment: @DonAntonio Also will do so thanks as well

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately this depends on your definition of irreducibility. Taking the definition used on both [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial) and [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrreduciblePolynomial.html), where a polynomial is irreducible if it cannot be factored into two non-constant polynomials you're pretty much correct, assuming that $p(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Suppose for contradiction that $p(x) = f(x)g(x)$ with $f(x),g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Then $f(x),g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ also, and so we have a factorisation in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, a contradiction.

Comment: there needs to be a condition on the gcd of the coefficients.

Comment: I'm guessing that people are downvoting this because "irreducibility" in $\mathbb Z[x]$ requires no non-trivial factors in $\mathbb Z$. I have seen people define "irreducible polynomial" as one not factoring as a product of two non-constant polynomials (in which case this is correct), but this seems less common.

Comment: Ah now that I see this comment my comment to the other answer becomes obsolete ;-)

Comment: @MiloBrandt I've edited to include this.

Answer (score 3):

This statement is false. For example, $p(x)=2x-2$ is obviously irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ but it is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ since $p(x)=2(x-1)$ and $2,x-1$ are not units in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

However the converse is true by Gauss' lemma.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is true so long as $p(x)$ is "primitive" in that the GCD of its roots is $1$.

Comment: Isnt the definition of "irreducible" that it can be factored into two _non-constant_ polynomials?

Comment: @EduardTetzlaff That's the case for fields but not for arbitrary rings.